# Sailsjs: Why is *return* used or not in the following code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm not clear as to why `return` is used or *not* in the following code. Please explain when it should and shouldn't be used or required to return the response.

```
  update: function(req, res) {
    var id = req.param('id');
    User
    .update(id, req.params.all())
    .exec(function(err, users) {
      if(err) return res.json(err, 400);
      var user = users[0];
      console.log('ID', user.id);
      User
      .findOne(user.id)
      .populate('profile')
      .exec(function (err, user){
        if (err) return res.json(err, 400);
        res.json(user, 201);
      });
    });
  },
```

Comment: FYI there's a number of problems with the posted code.  `populate` is not a valid model instance method; it's meant to be chained to a `find` or `findOne` call on a model *class*.  Also, the last `res.json` will *always* be executed, which will often result in `res.json` being called twice: once in the async code, and again at the bottom.  Please check your examples before you post them!

Comment: @ScottGress It seems the OP is new to async design patterns and the errors in his code are related to that green status. I don't believe he is in the wrong for sharing code he can't execute. You'll be hard pressed to find questions on SO that DON'T have bad code — thats the point of this forum.

Comment: @ScottGress that code was a response to another question which I since debugged and fixed - I've adjusted it to be working code although the question is more about the concept of `return` which my pythonic brain is starting to grasp

Comment: and yes I'm definitely new to async design patterns after decades of python

Comment: @mogga Thanks for the update.  If the question had been, "why isn't this working?", I would have gladly answered with code, but I'm a little hesitant to update the code in a *question*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` is used in the code in question as opposed to `else`.  The code could be rewritten as:

```
update: function(req, res) {
   var id = req.param('id');
   User
   .update(id, req.params.all())
   .exec(function(err, users) {
      if(err) {res.json(err, 400);} 
      // note the lack of "return" above, because in the case of an error
      // the code below will never run
      else {
         var user = users[0];
         console.log('ID', user.id);
         User
         .findOne(user.id)
         .populate('profile')
         .exec(function (err, user){
            if (err) {res.json(err, 400);} // again, no return
            else {res.json(user, 201);}
         });
      }
   });
};
```

But that requires you to keep track of more braces, and is possibly less efficient (although v8 probably optimizes the `else` in these cases).  You'll also see this convention used often when callbacks are involved:

```
function (req, res, next) {

  if (!req.session.loggedInUser) {
     return res.forbidden();
  }

  return next();

}
```

Again, you could rewrite using with `else`:

```
function (req, res, next) {

  if (!req.session.loggedInUser) {
     res.forbidden();
  } else {
     next();
  }

}
```

Notice an important difference here: in the `else`less code, if you leave out the first `return` you'll get into trouble because you'll send the `res.forbidden` response *and* execute the `next()` method, which you almost certainly don't want.  On the other hand in the `return`less code, if you were to add some more code after the `if/else`, it would get executed no matter *what*, which you also don't want.  So a good convention is to *always* return when you're using a callback (like `next()`) or executing code that will send a full response to the client (like `res.send` or `res.json`).

Answer (score 0):

`return` isn't used because there's a possibility that the code will be doing asynchronous operations. Async operations run "in parallel" or "later" or "just not in sequence", thus breaking the sequence of your code (Think of threads).

The usual practice is to provide a function (usually called a "callback") or an object that hosts a bunch of functions that can be called when your async operation finishes, instead of a `return`.

Comment: can you provide an example of what asynchronous operation would be happening in the context of sails and this code?

Comment: Both `exec` calls in the code are asynchronous, which is why they take a function as an argument.  When the asynchronous code is finished, it calls that function (the "callback") with the results.  You can see this at work by putting a log message before the last brace; it will be executed before the `console.log('ID', user.id)`.